# Проблема с RSA + MD160

Tags: rsa, c#

Помогите разобраться, коим образом с помощью только лишь открытого ключа проверить цифровую подпись, используя `RSACryptoServiceProvider` и hash-алгоритм `RIPEMD160Managed`?

Код примерно такой:

```
        // Инициализируем хэш-алгоритм
        var hashAlg = new RIPEMD160Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashAlg.ComputeHash(bytesToFile);

        // Подгружаем открытый ключ
        string openKey = File.ReadAllText(openKeyFileName, Encoding.Default);

        // Проверяем цифровую подпись
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(openKey);
        Array.Reverse(signature);
        bool ok = rsa.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("RIPEMD160"), signature);
        if (ok)
            MessageBox.Show("Цифровая подпись подтверждена!");
```

При вызове метода VerifyHash выбрасывается исключение:
"Object identifier (OID) is unknown."

Верхушка stack-trace следующая:

> `at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.OidToAlgId(String oid)
>    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(Byte[] rgbHash, String str, Byte[] rgbSignature)`

**Добавлено.**

Самое интересное, что OID для RIPEMD160 существует, но RSA принимать никак не хочет. К примеру, если использовать MD5 или SHA1, то всё в порядке.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash(v=vs.90).aspx

Плохо читал MSDN. В такой связке нужно использовать сторонние библиотеки по типу OpenSSL и иже с ними. Хотя и SHA256 тоже подходит, но об этом не написано.

Answer (score 1):

В такой связке невозможно [конкретно такими классами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash(v=vs.90).aspx) решить поставленную задачу невозможно.

> Допустимыми хэш-алгоритмами являются SHA1 и MD5.

В такой связке нужно использовать сторонние библиотеки по типу OpenSSL и иже с ними. Хотя и SHA256 тоже подходит, но об этом не написано.